# displaying old sha256 value after migrating sources from github

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I had a repository called `RepoA` in GitHub with some large files.
I migrated `RepoA` from GitHub to GitLab.

After that, I cloned `RepoA` sources from GitLab. If I run

```
git show file1.tar
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
+version https://git-lfs.github.com/****/v1
+oid sha256:*****************hgxs7y726726746881e7*****
+size 96776698
```

1. Why am I getting GitHub url here after migrating `RepoA` to GitLab?
2. Is there any way to remove GitHub old sha256 value attached to `file.tar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are pointer files used by Git LFS.  Since Git LFS stores large files outside of the main Git data, these files are used to locate the correct data.

To answer question 1, the URL in the `version` line is a version identifier, indicating the version of the Git LFS specification, not anything specific to your repository.  It's the same for all Git LFS files regardless of where they're hosted.

To answer question 2, the SHA-256 value of your file has not changed.  SHA-256 is a cryptographic hash function used to uniquely identify a file.  If the file had a given hash before, it will have the same hash now.

Note that when you use `git show`, by default it does not apply smudge or clean filters, such as those used by Git LFS, and will therefore show the pointer file for LFS files.  You can view the actual large file by doing this:

```
$ git -c diff.lfs.textconv=cat show --textconv file1.tar
```

However, usually tar files are not text files, so it isn't a good idea to display them to your terminal like that.

Comment: thanks for your response @bk2204.  1, when we change the content of git lfs file and push again to the repository, does SHA-256 value change?                            2, How can i add             [filter "lfs"]
 smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f            inside .git/config using git commands?

Comment: The SHA-256 value will change if the contents of the file change.  For 2, you can run `git lfs install --local --skip-smudge`.

Comment: thanks, last question, while pushing getting following lines:  LFS upload missing objects: (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s  (missing) file1.tar (*******0233f2bfbf22bcb011fef16f*******)    "I tried in so many ways but not able to push only after disabling git lfs i can push. but i want to push with git lfs"

Comment: also i ran $git config lfs.http://gitlab/test_group/ll1.git/info/lfs.locksverify true                            $git config lfs.allowincompletepush true        but i am getting pre-receive hook error.  then using $git lfs push origin master  getting :  LFS upload missing objects: (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s (missing) file1.tar (*******0233f2bfbf22bcb011fef16f*******)

Comment: suppose my lfs file *.tar is small in size, can i verify the cloned fine is pointer file or actual large file.  do i have any commands for this?  (assuming lfs file is pushed by someone and not by me)

Comment: You need to run `git lfs pull --all github`, where `github` is the remote of your GitHub remote, and then `git lfs push --all gitlab`, where `gitlab` is the remote of your GitLab remote.

Comment: how can i find difference between lfs pointer files and actual lfs file. i know by checking the file size we can know the difference.  But do we have any git commands to verify git lfs files and lfs pointer files. usually during inital cloning we clone pointer files later we will run git lfs pull

Comment: `git lfs ls-files` will show you different output depending on whether they're pointer files or large files.  `git lfs pointer` can be used to verify pointer files.  If you have more quesitons about this, I suggest opening new questions; comments aren't really suitable for thorough answers.